# Create a new column based on a conditional subtraction in python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, transform, subtraction

I'm trying to create a new column based on a conditional subtraction in python. I want to first group the dataframe by column A, then take the row value of C where B equals 2, and subtract that value from all values in column C.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
["R", 1, 2],
["R", 2, 4],
["R", 3, 6],
["R", 4, 8],
["S", 0, 5],
["S", 1, 4],
["S", 2, 1],
["S", 3, 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["a", "b", "c"])
df

Out[1]:
    a   b   c   
0   R   1   2   
1   R   2   4   
2   R   3   6   
3   R   4   8   
4   S   0   5   
5   S   1   4   
6   S   2   1   
7   S   3   3
```

Want it to yield the column 'd' of:

```
Out[2]:
    a   b   c   d   
0   R   1   2  -2
1   R   2   4   0 
2   R   3   6   2
3   R   4   8   4
4   S   0   5   4
5   S   1   4   3
6   S   2   1   0 
7   S   3   3   2
```

I would appreciate any tips of how to use transform or map functions to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to temporarily set the index to `a`. Then you can do the subtraction as usual while pandas will automatically align the index. Finally reset the index.

```
df1 = df.set_index('a')
df1['d'] = df1.c - df1.loc[df1.b.eq(2), 'c']
df1.reset_index()
```

Result:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  R  1  2 -2
1  R  2  4  0
2  R  3  6  2
3  R  4  8  4
4  S  0  5  4
5  S  1  4  3
6  S  2  1  0
7  S  3  3  2
```

(this of course only works if there is no more than one row for each value in `a` where `b` equals `2`)

Comment: Thanks, but does this method work if we would like to groupby more than one column?

Comment: I think so - the index will be a multiindex in this case, but the workings are the same

Comment: I got this error: "ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"

Comment: maybe it's better to ask a new question with new sample data, otherwise it's very hard to reproduce.